# Is there a way to calculate the madelung constant using exponentials?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

So I want to evaluate the Madelung constant for NaCl,
$$\sum_{\substack{j, k, \ell=-\infty\\\text{no}  
\, j=k=\ell=0}}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+k+\ell}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2+\ell^2}}.$$

My professor mentioned in class that there is a way of using exponentials to calculate this constant, but after a bit of searching all I found were other ways of series (that converges quicker), but that is not what I wanted. So what is the method of using exponentials?

Any references are appreciated.

Comment: Some ways of summing it are infinite even when you do exclude that term.

Comment: Are you not satisfied by wikipedia’s [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant) ? The $\text{sech}$ are shorthand for exponentials.

Comment: The correction is done to exclude the $j=k=\ell=0$ term. And to the Wikipedia formula: I think that my professor mentioned a method without using series, not a sum of exponentials.

Comment: *I think that my professor mentioned a method without using series, not a sum of exponentials.* Then you should ask your professor.

Comment: [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BensonsFormula.html) says no closed form is known. You probably misunderstood what your professor meant.

Comment: Maybe your instructor is talking about Ewald sums. [Here's](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/franz.vesely/simsp/dx/node47.html) and example.